# How to refresh fragment on spinner on item selected

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am setting a language in spinner on item selected. The change is not reflected on the next line. So, I want to refresh my fragment.

```
public class TodayChapter extends Fragment {
    String chapter_verse = "";
    TextView textView;
    ListView todayChapterListView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    DailyQuranMethods dailyQuranMethods = new DailyQuranMethods();
    private final String[] translateLanguage={"Translate To","English","Urdu","Hindi"};

    public TodayChapter() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_today_chapter, container, false);

        todayChapterListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.today_chapter_list_view);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.selectLanguage);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(),   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, translateLanguage );
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position)
                {
                    case 0:
                        dailyQuranMethods.setTranslationLanguage(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "english");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        dailyQuranMethods.setTranslationLanguage(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"english");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        dailyQuranMethods.setTranslationLanguage(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"urdu");
                        break;
                    default:
                        dailyQuranMethods.setTranslationLanguage(getActivity().getBaseContext(),"hindi");
                        break;

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        String[] chapter = dailyQuranMethods.getChapter(dailyQuranMethods.getChapterNoToday(getActivity().getBaseContext()), dailyQuranMethods.getTranslationLanguage(getActivity().getBaseContext()), getActivity());

        String chapterName = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chapters_name_arabic)[dailyQuranMethods.getChapterNoToday(getActivity().getBaseContext()) - 1 ];

        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.chapterName);
        textView.setText(chapterName);
        adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,chapter);

        todayChapterListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }

}
```

I can also call a method on each on item selected change. But, I want it by refreshing the fragment. In each switch case, I want to refresh the fragment. Please help me to solve this.

Edit 1:

There are three fragments, which are attached with the main activity:

```
mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Today's Verse"),
                TodayVerse.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Today's Chapter"),
                TodayChapter.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Complete Qur'an"),
                completeQuran.class, null);
```

Comment: Which activity is attached with this Fragment?

Comment: Main activity. Basically , I am using tabs here. One activity,three tabs

Comment: Okay, please have a look of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply detach and attach fragment as below

```
    Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tab2");
    FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
    fragTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
    fragTransaction.commit();
```

This will refresh the view and locale will change

Comment: I have just edited my question. What would be my tag?

Comment: are you setting tag in main activity?

Comment: So get the tag of your current fragment, which you have set already.

Comment: tab1, tab2 and tab3, is n't it?

Comment: Yes you can try this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81500/discussion-between-shoeb-siddique-and-learner).

Comment: LoL, ridiculous answer, script kiddie style. Without knowing what DailyQuranMethods does, it's hard to say but the way to go is probably a simple update method called from the spinner listener.